# Tinytex support package expl3 too old

Tags: r, latex, tinytex, huxtable

I'm trying to generate PDF reports with RMarkdown and Huxtable, and am using TinyTex latex distribution. I am receiving the following error message when trying to render a huxtable object to pdf:

```
! Package siunitx Error: Support package expl3 too old.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile C:\Users\XuR\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuelMWJ\file35687fc6629.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See file35687fc6629.log for more info.
```

I'm quite new to using Markdown and Latex in R, so not sure where this error is occuring from. Package versions: tinytex_0.44, huxtable_5.5.2. R version 4.1.0. Here is a simple reprex which is enough to reproduce the error on my machine. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
install.packages("huxtable")
library(huxtable)
car_ht <- as_hux(mtcars)
quick_pdf(car_ht)
```

Tried Reinstalling tinytex but it did not fix the problem

Comment: Well now I feel quite silly - apparently when I installed tinytex (the R package) I didn't actually use tinytex::install_tinytex() to install the distribution. I did that and now it seems to be running